# change random postions in matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have matrix fill with zeros

```
[
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

what is the most efficient way to change 5 random zeros with -1

```
[
  [0,-1,0,0,0],
  [0,0,-1,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0],
  [-1,0,-1,0,0],
  [0,0,-1,0,0]
]
```

I tried this solution but I think there is better than this

```
funtion solution(matrix:number[][],times = 5){
   if(times === 0) return
   const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * matrix.length)
   const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * matrix[i].length)
   if(matrix[i][j] === -1) return solution(matrix,times)
   matrix[i][j] = -1
   return solution(matrix,times - 1)
}
```

I want solution in any programming language
thank u for help

Answer (score 1):

```
construct empty set S
set size = col count * row count
while S size < 5
   generate random in range [ 0, size-1 ]
   insert random into S
loop r over S
   set row = r( modulus ) col_count
   set col = r- row * col_count 
   set matrix[ col, row ] = -1
```

In a set, the value of an element also identifies it (the value is itself the key ), and each value must be unique. e.g. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/

The algorithm assumes that the matrix is indexed with the col index changing  first.  If your matric is indexed the other way around, the you will have to change r loop to match